# AVG update january 2017 more than 1.5GB?

Tags: avg-antivirus

I installed NetLimiter to see broadband usage because I noticed that in last 5 days I spent 20Gb while I normally spend so much in whole month. After instaling it I noticed that just today c:/program files (x86)/avg/avg2013/avgmfapx.exe had downloaded in less than 15 hours for 1.6GB files and uploaded 23,61MB and the usage is still increasing. Is that normal?
[image]

Comment: Of a course of what period exactly?

Comment: Today, less than 15 hours.

Comment: NetLimiter is reporting the wrong usage for the process, the only other possability, is your not reading the report correctly.

Comment: I think it is reporting correct usage because elevated usage matches with the Current Flux: report from my modem which is very high. I believe I am reading it correctly, see the image I just attached to question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there was a bug inside AVG. I tried to download update manually and it showed .bin file can not be found error. For this reason it was trying to download update constantly. I cleared download update history. After that update was successful and broadband usage stopped increasing.